# how command pattern parametrize clients with different requests?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

The intent of command pattern is "Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you **parametrize clients with different requests**..." Can someone explain what does parametrization clients with different requests means? and how command pattern parametrizes clients with different requests?

Any Explanation in this regard will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ICommand
{
    public:
    virtual ~ICommand()
    {}
    virtual int InitCommand() = 0;
    virtual int ExecuteCommand() = 0;
    virtual int FinalizeCommand() = 0;
};

class CCommandProcessor
{
    public:
        virtual ~ICommandProcessor()
        {}
        int ProcessCommand(ICommand *_pCommand);
        {
            int iResult = _pCommand->InitCommand();
            if(iResult == 0)
            {
                cout << "InitCommand Failed" << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            iResult = _pCommand->ExecuteCommand();
            if(iResult == 0)
            {
                cout << "ExecuteCommand Failed" << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            iResult = _pCommand->FinalizeCommand();
            if(iResult == 0)
            {
                cout << "FinalizeCommand Failed" << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            return 1;
        }
}

class CCopyDocumentCommand : public ICommand
{
    private:
        std::string m_szDocumentName;
        std::string m_szSavePath;       

    public:
        CCopyDocumentCommand(std::string _szDocumentName, std::_szSavePath)
        {
            m_szDocumentName = _szDocumentName;
            m_szSavePath = _szSavePath;
        }
        virtual int InitCommand()
        {
            //check the document save path valid.
            //check the document for any errors.            
        }
        virtual int ExecuteCommand()
        {
            //copy the document
        }
        virtual int FinalizeCommand()
        {
            //delete temporaries if used.
        }
};

class CPrintDocumentCommand : public ICommand
{
    private:
        std::string m_szDocumentName;
        std::string m_szPageSettings;       
        int iTopMargin;
        int iLeftMargin
    public:
        CPrintDocumentCommand(std::string _szDocumentName, std::_szPageSettings, int _iTopMargin, int iLeftMargin)
        {
            m_szDocumentName = _szDocumentName;
            m_szPageSettings = _szPageSettings;
            m_iTopMargin = _iTopMargin;
            m_iLeftMargin = _iLeftMargin;
        }
        virtual int InitCommand()
        {
            //check the page settings.
            //check the document for any errors.
            //check printer
        }
        virtual int ExecuteCommand()
        {
            //print the document;
        }
        virtual int FinalizeCommand()
        {
            //delete temporary if used.
        }
};


CCommandProcessor  oProcessor;
CPrintDocumentCommand oPrintCommand("c:\\data\\report.txt", "some settings", 5, 5);
CCopyDocumentCommand oCopyCommand("c:\\data\\report.txt", "c:\\data\\report_.txt");

oProcessor.ProcessCommand(&oPrintCommand);
oProcessor.ProcessCommand(&oCopyCommand);
```

As you can see the same `CommandProcessor` executes different commands which work on different set of parameters.
That is, the `Command Pattern` allows you to convert `parameters` of a `command function` to `data members` of a `command object`.

Comment: Thanks for you quick Reply...  I have one confusion that Participants in command pattern are Command, ConcreteCommand, Client, Invoker and Receiver, In above mentioned example can u please identify who is acting as client  which is parameterized with different requests using command pattern?

Comment: In order to understand Command Pattern, consider the working of a CPU. Jobs/Processes are scheduled on CPU. Every Job/Process has different set of data(parameters) to work on. Yet the same CPU executes different kind of Jobs/Processes. In the example, commands are Jobs/Processes and the CommandProcessor is the framework/CPU on top of which different jobs/commands which work on different parameters can be scheduled. Clients/Application use different command objects to execute different tasks. So, there are `Application/Clients`, `Command Objects` and `Command Processing Framework`.

Comment: In this example, again I think **receiver** of a command is parameterized, not **client**, Isn't it? if it is not, please help me in clearing my confusion that how client is parameterized with different requests using command pattern?

Comment: In simple terms, if you want to perform some functionality then you need logic and data which will be utilized inside the logic. That is, lets say `print(x)`, `print` is the functionality and `x` is the data. Now if you combine functionality and data inside an object then what you get is a `command object`. This `command object` therefore has the logic as well as data to perform a particular functionality required by the command which is represented by the `command object`. Now, you can simply pass the `command object` and get the functionality done. You pass command objects to same processor

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more detailed [structure diagram](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command) of Command:
[image]
From this structure, you can see that the "parameterized objects" should be the parameter of the setCommand() method in the **Invoker** class, the type of the parameter is **Command interface**.

So "parametrize clients with different requests" should means that **you can pass different instance of command, then you can achieve different operations with the same executeCommand() method calling**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear (to me) what parameterize really means here. I suspect that it just means that you can give each client's receiver a bunch of different requests.

Under Applicability, [gof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) goes on to say: 'Use the Command pattern when you want to

parameterize objects by an action to perform, as MenuItem objects did above. You can express such parameterization in a procedural language with a callback function, that is, a function that's registered somewhere to be called at a later point. Commands are an object-oriented replacement for callbacks. ...'